# CakePHP 2.0.0-RC2 Console baking error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I originally thought this error had to do with my path setup - I had
separated the core from the app so I could work more easily with git
submodules, so I ignored it. I just did a fresh checkout from the git
repo / a download of the RC2 source / and a cakeinit install of the
2.0 package (also uses git) and all 3 installs have the same issue I
had before.

My code seems to work fine via the browser.

The output of a ./cake bake Model from inside the local copy of the
core in the lib/Cake/Console folder is here
https://gist.github.com/1233884

This totally prevents me from using bake. Baking a project doesn't
work, baking a new database config doesn't work - it also doesn't
matter which of the datasources I try.

Can someone point me in the right direction here? I want to use some
of the bake tools and work on converting some shells for 2.0.

I am using XAMPP (latest version for OS X - I reinstalled it 20
minutes ago as a last ditch attempt)
OSX 10.5.8

The database.php I am working with is here with the passwords removed
but otherwise working
https://gist.github.com/1233891

I have tested it with and without the unix_socket setting and encoding
settings. All works fine from the browser but again not via the cli.

Comment: Any luck running `cake` from inside your `app` directory instead? `/Users/abba/Sites/foundry/app> ../lib/Cake/Console/cake bake Model`

Comment: No - the output is exactly the same.

Comment: This problem also happens in Arch Linux when you install Apache PHP mySQL . You have to uncomment `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in php.ini to solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, the error message could have been be a little bit more specific:

> Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

`DboSource::__construct()` is throwing that error [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/8d437648012e8d17fcea826b43c67a237bc06a4b/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L238) because `Mysql::enabled()` returns false:

```
public function enabled() {
    return in_array('mysql', PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
}
```

On Windows, I can reproduce your error by commenting out the following line from my PHP CLI's `php.ini` file  (the one that running `php --ini` on the command-line returns):

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql_libmysql.dll
```

HTH.

Comment: I reproduced the error from another (working) machine by commenting out the extension=pdo_mysql.so in the php.ini file - it would appear the cli php included with XAMPP does not enable this extension but I can't be sure until I get to back to the other machine this evening but I think you are right.

Comment: I take it back - I managed to reproduce the error by running php with *no* ini file - but when I comment out the pdo_mysql extension in MAMP or XAMPP on OSX the cli running 5.3.4 still works as expected but the cli running 5.3.1 does not. I still have to confirm the extension on the other machine later this evening.

Comment: I think it might be this bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50829 which was fixed in 5.3.2.

Comment: Using WAMP (which comes with a 5.3.4 php install) seems to work - using XAMPP (5.3.1) does not - both claim to b loading pdo_mysql / mysqli correctly. Upgrading fixes it - I haven't tried a non-stable XAMPP build yet with the higher php version installed but that might help anyone else having this problem.

Comment: Correction * I meant MAMP not WAMP in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I was MAMP on Mac and had the same problem with CakePHP 2.2.  I solved the problem by installing the mysql pdo for my mac ports installation. `sudo port install php5-mysql`

Answer (score -1):

For local testing, I have found that setting the host to the address works. In my config I use the following:

'host' => '127.0.0.1',

This works for Mamp Pro